# How to debug an email template?

Tags: php, email, email-templates, debug

I am working on modifying email templates. `{themeName}/template/email/order/items/order/default.phtml`

The above template triggers when the user (*guest or customer*) has placed the order.

In the above template, there are some variables like:

```
$_item = $this->getItem();
$_order = $this->getItem()->getOrder();
```

if I use any debugging methods like `Mage::log` or `zend_debug::dump`, the checkout page is hanging up and the order is never being processed.

So, my question is what should I use to debug email templates here?

I also used `echo` which is always showing an empty string or `array` for an array holding variable.

Comment: Can someone please atleast tell me how to get order_id from the above variables?

Comment: Have you tried to use `Mage::log` in the block class (`Mage_Sales_Block_Order_Email_Items_Order_Default`)?

Comment: @nevvermind I tried `Mage::log` in `Mage_Sales_Block_Items_Abstract`. which has the same issue as I mentioned above in my post. I didn't get relation to your mentioned class.

Comment: The email tpl is in `app/locale/en_US/template/email/sales/order_new_guest.html` (for guest). There, a layout handle is inserted - `sales_email_order_items`. This handle is declared in `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/sales.xml`. The template you're having problems with has the block set to `sales/order_email_items_order_default` - aka `Mage_Sales_Block_Order_Email_Items_Order_Default`.

Comment: @nevvermind Thanks for the info. Actually, I am getting the products html to the email from `{themeName}/template/email/order/items/order/default.phtml`  (_I checked it thoroughly_) The other part of email like "Thank you for purchasing.. blah blah blah" is coming from what you have mentioned above (_I didn't check but I think so_). To be frank, I solved this problem but my question is how to debug in these email templates?

Comment: Yes, the `app/locale/en_US/template/email/sales/order_new_guest.html` tpl is the whole email body, and the `Mage_Sales_Block_Order_Email_Items_Order_Default` block (with its `{themeName}/template/email/order/items/order/default.phtml` tpl) is used as a *per-line-item* renderer.  But I can `Mage::log($_order->getId())` in `Mage_Sales_Block_Order_Email_Items_Order_Default`. Did you tried to do a `Mage::log` on the entire order object? That would choke your server, because you're trying to print_r a big/deep object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the hackathon we (read as they :-)) implemented a module to preview mail templates: https://github.com/magento-hackathon/E-MailPreview

Maybe this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You could also try `Mage::log($your_object->debug());` this will hopefully give you the information that you need.

It will show you all the objects data as an array of key => value and will show you the class of any sub-data that is an object.

```
if (is_scalar($value)) {
    $debug[$key] = $value;
} elseif (is_array($value)) {
    $debug[$key] = $this->debug($value, $objects);
} elseif ($value instanceof Varien_Object) {
    $debug[$key.' ('.get_class($value).')'] = $value->debug(null, $objects);
}
```